# How do I align code on dot/period (.)?

Tags: regular-expressions, align

I recently switched to emacs. Just wanted to see how it works and if it'll help with productivity.

Right now I'm working in Haskell, which means a lot of function composition with `.` operator.

I have a code block that looks like this

```
certainat :: Certain -> Maybe Double
certainat = join . fmap at . certainCalls . certainEffects

certainld :: Certain -> Maybe Double
certainld = join . fmap maybeIDFunctionCallld . certainCalls . certainEffects

certainxin :: Certain -> Maybe Double
certainxin = join . fmap insert . certainCalls . certainEffects
```

and I want to align entire block on `.`

Reading through wiki docs, I tried doing it with `C-u` `M-x` `align-regexp` `.\(\)` but the result was weird spacing between characters. Plus that only worked on one line.

What should I do?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the same command with different parameters:

```
Complex align using regexp: \(\.\)
Parenthesis group to modify (justify if negative): -1
Amount of spacing (or column if negative): 0
Repeat throughout line? y
```

Output:

```
certainat :: Certain -> Maybe Double
certainat = join  . fmap at                    . certainCalls . certainEffects

certainld :: Certain -> Maybe Double
certainld = join  . fmap maybeIDFunctionCallld . certainCalls . certainEffects

certainxin :: Certain -> Maybe Double
certainxin = join . fmap insert                . certainCalls . certainEffects
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!          Also one more question if you wouldn't mind, is it possible to align the first word `join` and also align on `.`?

Comment: Just run `align-regexp` on `join` (or even `=`) without `C-u` before aligning on the dot.